# pytest and codecov: no coverage report found

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, pytest, travis-ci

I have created a brand new [Python repository](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit) based on a cookie-cutter template. Everything looks okay, so I am trying now to set the testing and testing coverage using travis and codecov. I am new to pytest but I am trying to do things right. After looking on the internet, I ended up with this setup:

In [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/blob/master/.travis.yml), I have added the following:

```
install: 
  - pip install -U tox-travis
  - pip install coverage
  - pip install codecov

script:
    - python setup.py install
    - tox
    - coverage run tests/test_foo.py
```

In my [`tox.ini`](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/blob/master/tox.ini) file:

```
[testenv]
passenv = CI TRAVIS TRAVIS_*
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}
    PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1
deps =
    pipenv
    codecov
    pytest
    {py27}: pathlib2
commands_pre = 
    pipenv install --dev --skip-lock
    codecov
```

I have created a minimal [`tests/test_foo.py`](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/blob/master/tests/test_foo.py) file with the following (`foo()` is the only function currently present in the package).

```py
import pytest
import doctest
import neurokit2 as nk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
    pytest.main()

def test_foo():
    assert nk.foo() == 4
```

I have It seems that codecov, triggered by travis does not run through the test. Moreover, on travis, it says [`Error: No coverage report found`](https://travis-ci.org/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/jobs/604805529#L332)  I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think one problem is that `pytest` is not quite locating your test file; by default, [it needs to have the form `test_*.py` or `*_test.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery), if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) create pytest.ini file in your project directory and add the following lines

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
python_files = *.py
python_functions = test_*
```

2) create .coveragerc file in project directory and add the following lines

```
[report]
fail_under = 90
show_missing = True
```

3) pytest for code coverage

```
pytest --verbose --color=yes --cov=Name of directory for which you need code coverage --assert=plain
```

Note: Name of the directory for which you need code coverage must be inside the project directory

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing `coverage` on your installs. You have it on scripts but it might not be running. Try adding `pip install coverage` in your travis.yml file. Have a go at this too: [codecov](https://github.com/codecov/example-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions! I have added `pip install coverage` and have renamed the [test file](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/tree/master/tests), but unfortunately, both solutions did not [work](https://travis-ci.org/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/jobs/605461342#L336)... Any more suggestions?